# Why are empty strings not captured with the index() method on lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list, methods

I'm trying to get the indices of cells in rows. It is working fine as long as I don't encounter empty strings. The following is a MWE.

The following works -- there are no empty strings:

```
table = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]

for row in table[1:]:
    row_ind = table.index(row)
    for cell in row:
        col_ind = row.index(cell)
        print('row_ind: ' + str(row_ind) + ' | col_ind: ' + str(col_ind))
```

As expected the output is:

```
row_ind: 1 | label_ind: 0
row_ind: 1 | label_ind: 1
row_ind: 1 | label_ind: 2
row_ind: 2 | label_ind: 0
row_ind: 2 | label_ind: 1
row_ind: 2 | label_ind: 2
```

However, with some of the strings are empty, like in the following example:

```
table = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '', ''], ['', '', '6']]

for row in table[1:]:
    row_ind = table.index(row)
    for cell in row:
        col_ind = row.index(cell)
        print('row_ind: ' + str(row_ind) + ' | col_ind: ' + str(col_ind))
```

The indices in the output are off:
(The problem also occurs when I have zeros instead of empty strings):

```
row_ind: 1 | col_ind: 0
row_ind: 1 | col_ind: 1
row_ind: 1 | col_ind: 1
row_ind: 2 | col_ind: 0
row_ind: 2 | col_ind: 0
row_ind: 2 | col_ind: 2
```

If I replace all empty strings with 'na', like this:

```
table = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '', ''], ['', '', '6']]

table_new = []

for row in table:
    row_new = []
    for cell in row:
        if cell == '' or cell == '0':
            cell = 'na'
            row_new.append(cell)
        else:
            row_new.append(cell)
    table_new.append(row_new)

for row in table_new[1:]:
    row_ind = table_new.index(row)
    for cell in row:
        col_ind = row.index(cell)
        print('row_ind: ' + str(row_ind) + ' | col_ind: ' + str(col_ind))
```

The indices in the output are still off:

```
row_ind: 1 | col_ind: 0
row_ind: 1 | col_ind: 1
row_ind: 1 | col_ind: 1
row_ind: 2 | col_ind: 0
row_ind: 2 | col_ind: 0
row_ind: 2 | col_ind: 2
```

A fix would be fantastic so I can use indices but I would be fine with an alternative. Any help and/or explanation would be welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It obviously  returns "the **lowest** index in the string where substring is found" - expected behaviour. And it's not only for "empty" values - but for any repetitive value in sequence

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you're right. I didn't read that properly and misunderstood what it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks go to @RomanPerekhrest who pointed out that I was trying to use the index() method the wrong way.

I solved the problem with `enumerate` – this provides exactly the functionality I was look for. Here is my MWE again:

```
table = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '', ''], ['', '', '6']]

for row in table[1:]:
    row_ind = table.index(row)
    for cell in enumerate(row):
        col_ind = cell[0]
        print('row_ind: ' + str(row_ind) + ' | col_ind: ' + str(col_ind))
```

This now gives me:

```
row_ind: 1 | col_ind: 0
row_ind: 1 | col_ind: 1
row_ind: 1 | col_ind: 2
row_ind: 2 | col_ind: 0
row_ind: 2 | col_ind: 1
row_ind: 2 | col_ind: 2
```

For anyone who runs into a similar problem, [here is what enumerate does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).